# Cron job using pre-mounted samba share, not sure if safe...?

Tags: cron, backup, rsync, samba, cifs

I'm using fstab to mount a samba share on boot

```
//ip/share /mnt/share cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,uid=user 0 0
```

and scheduled rsync via cron job to copy the contents to a local drive once a week

```
0 2 * * 7 /usr/bin/rsync -av --delete /mnt/share/ /mnt/backup/ --log-file=/var/log/rsyncbackup.log
```

The thought came to mind if the host was unavailable /mnt/share would be empty- if the cron job ran it'd wipe all the data on my local backup mount because of the difference and --delete flag.  I want to keep that as I want a clone of my share.

I'm relatively new with Linux and curious what approach might add a safeguard to this.  could I run "ls" to check for content, if present continue?  Otherwise what would ensure I don't inadvertently delete everything on my backup mount?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by reading the manual a little bit more on rsync and ssh.

1. Generated ssh key on client `ssh-keygen`
2. Copied to host `ssh-copy-id user@host`
3. Modified cron job `0 2 * * 7 /usr/bin/rsync -av --delete user@ip:/mnt/driveuid/share/ /mnt/backup/ --log-file=/var/log/rsyncbackup.log`

Now if my computer can't connect to the host the job doesn't run.